# Migrate maven artifacts into Cloudbees repository

Tags: maven, nexus, cloudbees, artifactory

Has anyone ever migrated an existing maven repository into Cloudbees repositories?

Currently, I have a self-hosted Sonatype Nexus instance with three custom repositories (snapshots, releases, and 3rd-party libraries not hosted in Maven). I have an existing Cloudbees CI environment, and I'm looking at migrating my maven storage as well.

If anyone has any helpful hints, tips, or an existing migration guide, please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to `zip`/`tar.gz` up your existing repository and upload it to the DAV repository in question.

Submit a support request and it can be unpacked on the server (DAV is quite slow for moving lots of files)